# Сложение чисел

Tags: php

Только изучаю пхп, пишу программку для сложениях двух чисел

```
<?php
echo '<form name="calculator" method="post" action="" style="display: inline;">
    <input name="a" type="text" size="3"> + <input name="b" type="text" size="3"></form>' . ' = ' . '<div>' . $c . '</div>';
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
if (is_int($a) && is_int($b)) {
    $c = $a + $b;
} elseif (!is_int($a)) {
    echo "Первое значение не является целым числом";
} elseif (!is_int($b)) {
    echo "Второе значение не является целым числом";
} else {
    echo "Оба введенных значения не являются целыми числами";
}
?>
```

Появилось несколько вопросов:

1. Можно ли в форме обойтись без кнопки submit, чтобы числа считывались автоматически и складывались?
2. Как правильно сделать вывод итогового числа?
3. У меня всегда выводится "Первое значение не является целым числом" еще до того, как числа введены, не могу разобраться, как тут правильно сделать.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Учите JavaScript, если клиентской web разработки силу познать хотите вы

Comment: хочу, но вопрос был про пхп

Comment: > Можно ли в форме обойтись без кнопки submit, чтобы числа считывались автоматически и складывались?

js:`XMLHttpRequest()`

Comment: >Учите JavaScript, если клиентской web разработки силу познать вы хотите

Магистр Йода ))

Answer (score 4):

1. Нет, к php это не имеет отношения, это html + javascript ([пример калькулятора на javascript](http://on-line-teaching.com/js/js.math.sample.htm))
2. ?? echo "Итог сложения {$a} + {$b} = {$c}";
3. И это правильно! Ибо первое условие уже не отрабатывает, потому что нет значения `$_POST['a']` Лучше так сделать:

   ```
   if ( isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['b']) ) {  
       $a = $_POST['a']; $b = $_POST['b'];    
       if (is_int($a) && is_int($b)) {
           $c = $a + $b; } elseif (!is_int($a)) {
           echo "Первое значение не является целым числом"; }
       elseif (!is_int($b)) {
           echo "Второе значение не является целым числом";
       }
       else {
           echo "Оба введенных значения не являются целыми числами";
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: мне кажется или парсер лох? -_-

Comment: оно както криво скопипастилось, спасибо)

Comment: На самом деле - 4 пробела должны идентифицировать блок кода, но, в этом случае, почему-то это не происходило и пришлось воспользоваться "хаком" :)

Comment: Если код добавляется в список, то его идентифицируют 8 пробелов.

Comment: @Iranda, спасибо, буду знать, но, имхо, 8 пробелов это уже слишком, почему не, например, 5?

Comment: Наверное, потому что 8 пробелов равнозначны 2-м tab'ам:  
1-й tab - маркер списка,  
2-й tab - маркер кода